# The image that iOS shows when app goes into background appears upside down when seen in portrait mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8

Im building an iOS app which is Landscape only. When my app goes into background, the image that iOS shows in the multitasking apps list appears messed up. It is showing the landscape image upside down in portrait mode.

I'm not doing anything specific in `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

Here's an image showing the issue.

[image: Screenshot showing the list of apps running currently]

I've allowed only Landscape mode for my app by setting these in General properties and Info.plist files as shown below:

[image: App's General properties showing Device Orientation locked to Landscape only]

Info.plist file:

[image: Info.plist file showing the supported orientations for the app]

It sure does look like one of the third-party ad libraries is causing the mess-up. The issue does not occur in the ad-free version of the same app. Is there anything I can do to prevent the third party libraries from causing this mess up?

So, I'm using iAd and AdMob along with adapters to support mediation (to support InMobi, MobFox and Millennial Media).

Is there anything I can do to get this fixed?

Comment: upvoted for a visually awesome bug.

Comment: Wow, a famous painter appreciated the visuals on this question :)

Comment: This might be bit of a brute force method, but have you tried using the ad networks separately to see which one (it at all) might be causing this problem. I'm from InMobi and I haven't seen anyone face this issue with our SDK before.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue in a fresh project just after adding AdMob. But, is there anything I can do to prevent the third party libraries from causing this mess up?

Comment: Can't figure out why this is happening. Did some googling and this video showed up: https://plus.google.com/+ArmandoFerreira/posts/GE4XSEJBN5G?pid=5927382879159772482&oid=113385956777514004917

So you're not the only one who's faced this issue.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to remove the ad from superview in `applicationWillResignActive` and re-adding it in `applicationDidBecomeActive` (preferably making use of NSNotifications).

So removing it would look something like this:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    [self.adBanner removeFromSuperview];
}
```

And adding it:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    [self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
    [self.view addConstraints:@[self.adXConstraint, self.adYConstraint]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a new one. The only way that I know of where you can affect the multitasking snapshot is for background fetches where you call the completion handler provided to you in a background fetch callback.

I did a quick test on one of my apps by locking it into landscape mode and it didn't do this.
How are you locking your app into landscape? Are you using the "General" tab under your project target settings? There's a section where you can set your app orientation.

In my opinion, a hack in your code to lock orientation might cause this kind of behavior.

Comment: I've updated my question with additional information on how I'm locking my app into landscape-only.

Comment: Are you using any third party libraries to render your UI? Some of your controls don't look like the native iOS controls.

Comment: I am not using any third-party libraries to render the UI.

Comment: It sure does look like one of the third-party ad libraries is causing the mess-up. The issue does not occur in the ad-free version of the same app. Is there anything I can do to prevent the third party libraries from causing this mess up?

Comment: What's the library? You need to file an issue with them if this is the case. Could you include all relevant information in your question? Why aren't you using iAd?